# Why is the menu not being added to the Toolbar in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-toolbar

I am attempting to add a simple menu to my Toolbar, but it is not displaying.

Here is my Activity:

```
package com.github.crmepham.bluetoothmessenger.activities

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import android.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class ConversationsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mTopToolbar: Toolbar? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(com.github.crmepham.bluetoothmessenger.R.layout.conversation_list)
        mTopToolbar = findViewById(com.github.crmepham.bluetoothmessenger.R.id.my_toolbar)
        setActionBar(mTopToolbar)
    }

    override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(com.github.crmepham.bluetoothmessenger.R.menu.main_menu, menu)

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(com.github.crmepham.bluetoothmessenger.R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.getItemId()

        if (id == com.github.crmepham.bluetoothmessenger.R.id.action_favorite) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ConversationsActivity, "Action clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return true
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

The `conversation_list.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/HeaderBar"
    android:elevation="4dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `main_menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.github.crmepham.bluetoothmessenger.activities.ConversationsActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>

</menu>
```

and the `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.github.crmepham.bluetoothmessenger"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
}
```

Could someone help me understand why the menu is not getting added to the `Toolbar`?

Comment: You're using the framework `Toolbar`, and `ActionBar` methods. `AppCompatActivity` works with the androidx library `Toolbar`, and the corresponding support `ActionBar` methods. That is, `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`, and `setSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: on top of what @MikeM. said, please use the toolbar from the support library

Comment: @Blackbelt What is the difference?

Comment: backwards compatibility

Comment: If you mean, what do you need to change, I was editing my comment. Have another look. (I had to double-check the new `Toolbar` package name.)

Comment: @MikeM. I made that change but get the following exception `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`.

Comment: You have to change the layout element, too; i.e.,  `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>`.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot that part. That works, thank you. Feel free to answer.

Comment: Your problem is on method "onPrepareOptionsMenu". It returns super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) instead of super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)

Comment: sorry for kind-of-offtopic, but I try hard now to find what question mark in `Bundle?` means and I could not. Could you point me to some guide, docs?

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov That is `Kotlin` syntax to allow the value of Bundle to be null initially.

Comment: thanx! again sorry and please take no offence, I used java but not Kotlin. Is is correct to say that all you code is Kotlin and java tag is kind-of attention grabber like `c` would be for `c++` code? I actually glad I saw it - could be switching to Kotlin myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `android.widget.Toolbar` class and the `setActionBar()` method are from the native framework. The androidx `AppCompatActivity`, and its options menu methods, will deal only with the `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` class, and that needs to be set as the support `ActionBar`, with the corresponding `setSupportActionBar()` method.

You will also need to use the fully-qualified class name in the `Toolbar`'s layout element. That is, change it to `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>`.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is inside your "onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)" method:

```
    override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(com.github.crmepham.bluetoothmessenger.R.menu.main_menu, menu)

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

You return "super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)" instead of "super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)".

I guess if you change that, it is going to work